# Simple Java array question

Tags: java, arrays

[Codingbat.com array question](http://codingbat.com/prob/p185685)

This is a simple array question, not for homework, just for general knowledge before I take another programming class next fall.

Given an array of ints, return true if 6 appears as either the first or last element in the array. The array will be length 1 or more.

```
firstLast6({1, 2, 6}) → true
firstLast6({6, 1, 2, 3}) → true
firstLast6({3, 2, 1}) → false
```

The problem I have is that you are not supposed to use any loops to traverse the array. How can this be written to avoid an index out of bounds exception if I don't know the total number of ints in the input data?

My solution --- it works but not exactly the answer they were looking for.

```
public boolean firstLast6(int[] nums) {
  for (int i=0; i < (nums.length ); i++)
  {

  if (i == 0 && nums[i] == 6)
  { 
  return true;
  }

  else if (i == (nums.length - 1) && nums[i] ==6)
  {

  return true;
  }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I think the array length is already known to you as you have written: `nums.length` then whats the problem?? just use nums[0] for first element and nums[nums.length-1] for last element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use the `length` property to access the last index:

```
public boolean firstLast6(int[] nums) {
    if (nums == null || nums.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return nums[0] == 6 || nums[nums.length - 1] == 6;
}
```

EDIT: added check for null or empty array.

Comment: That's a lot easier than the method I was using. I wasn't aware that you could return a boolean like that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Peter thanks, updated. @user733952 sure! Essentially you're returning the result of the logical condition, which is a boolean. You could store the result in a variable then return that, but for such a short piece of code this approach is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Adding special checks for nulls is usually just masking programming bugs :) (sorry for nitpicking, I'm shutting up now)

Answer (score 1):

Simply retrieve the first array element, and the last array element.  That is:

```
nums[0]
nums[nums.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey , you don't need any loops for this . All you have to do is :

```
if(array[0]==6 || array[array.length-1]==6){
    return true ;
}
  else{
     return false ; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most compact and efficient expression of this would be

```
public void firstLast(int[] a) {
  return a.length > 0 && (a[0] == 6 || a[a.length-1] == 6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the output can be easily obtained by

```
if(array[0]==6||array[nums.length]==6)
return true;
else
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is full code for this problem,i hope this gonna help you

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class pair13 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] number=new int[6];



    Scanner ss=new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int j = 0; j < number.length; j++) {
        number[j]=ss.nextInt();

    }

    firstLast6( number);
    System.out.print(firstLast6(number));
}



 public static boolean firstLast6( int[] nums ) {

     if ( nums[0]==6 || nums[nums.length-1]==6 ){
                   return true;
     }
     else{

         return false;

     }
}




}
```

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine.

```
public boolean firstLast6(int[] nums) {
      int length=nums.length;
      if(nums[0]==6||nums[length-1]==6){
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```